# Restoring a MySql table from a .sql file; why is the corresponding .idb file so much larger?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, database-restore

I am restoring a 10 GB table using MySql 5.6 Workbench.  I noticed that there is a .idb file with a name that corresponds to the table name in c:\ProgramData....\Mysql\data and that file is increasing in size while this restore takes place.  However, I have noticed that the size of the .idb file is almost 2 GB's larger then the original .sql file (and growing (it was originally a .dump file)).  Can anyone tell me why this is?  The progress bar in my WorkBench does not work, and I want to get an estimation about how far along in the restore I am.

Comment: do u have different encoding between the two DBs?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, the corresponding .idb file is much larger to facilitate faster lookups. For example, the space used for various indexes in your .sql file will only be the statement to create the indexs. However, the actual indexes in your .idb file will be MUCH larger the the statements to create them.

Answer (score 0):

Dump and idb files have totally different formats. The first is a text file while the other one is a binary file maintained by the MySQL server. Whatever is stored there simply takes more space that the simple text representation. As simple as that.

You neither can prevent the creation of the idb file, nor control what it contains. So, just accept that the file grows large while you import a big db.